# C - Concatenate char arrays, then write to stdout different to writing single chars

Tags: c, arrays, char, mandelbrot

so I have this task to create mandel fractals in C.
I will keep the code simple as it's quite much.
The Problem:

- in the given file, each pixel (char[3]) is calculated separately and then written to stdout via write(1, pixeldata, 3)
- NOW: as this is not very efficient, I want to first collect all pixels of one line in a char array char line[width*3]
- everything works, except that the output is very different from the one before (colors look displaced, etc.)

Here's the code:

```
char pixelData[3];
char line[width*3];
for (y=1; y <= height; ++y) {
...
    for (x=1; x <= width; ++x) {
    ... calculate ...

    // iterate
        for ( .... calculate ...) {
               ... calculate ....
        }
        strncat(line, pixelData, 3);        // after
        // write(1, pixelData, 3);  // before: worked
}
write(1, line, sizeof(line)); // after
memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));
```

}

It would be pretty cool, if someone could tell me, what I did wrong here...
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use `memcpy` instead of `strncpy` The pixel data might have 0s in between them

Comment: Sounds like an idea but I used strcat/strncat to concatenate the values (line + newPixelData) and I don't know about something equivalent to that for memcpy

Comment: Thank you, using memcpy and a pointer to the new index in the array worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use string functions with `char` arrays which might contain 0s, nor with `char` arrays which are not 0-terminated. I believe that `pixelData` in your code is just an array of three small integers, rather than a printable string. So `strncat` won't help you. On the other hand, since you always know how long your line is, you don't need `strncat` to work it out for you.

Comment: You're right, pixelData contains of three values for RGB.
As I want to first generate a whole line (so append those three values to the existing line) which is (width*3) long before I write it to stdout, how else would I do this?

Comment: @iwilltry: think of it as an array of triplets. The first triplet occupies positions 0-2; the next one 3-5; then 4-6; and so on. (Or you could use two dimensional array.) You might want to look at `memcpy`.

Comment: Thank you, I worked it out like this: use an int as a running index for the current location in the line[]-array, than memcpy(&line[i*3], pixelData, 3); and increment i.
Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction :)